# Why does different char-width occur in Vim and Nvim?

Tags: vim, utf-8, char, neovim

Why does different char-width occur in Vim and Nvim ? And how to make it same?

Like the following graph. In Vim, the char is double-width, but in Nvim it is single-width.

[image]

```
12345
│││
│││
│x
```

You can copy the words and test.

Comment: Where did you take those screenshots? In the TUI or in the GUI?

Comment: In TUI.  Windows terminal.

Comment: I found the reason is 'ambiwidth' option , and now it is solved.

Comment: Consider writing a short answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason is 'ambiwidth' option.

`set ambiwidth=double` make it difference behavior.

`set ambiwidth=single` display one-width normally.